# Correct sequence of actions when using Markdown & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, markdown, sanitization

I want my users to be able to write an article in Markdown, have it stored in the MySQL database (with the option to edit it in the future), and displayed for other users.

In practice, this is my understanding of how it works:

INPUT

2. user input via HTML form using Markdown syntax
3. `$queryInput = mysql_real_escape_string($userInput);`
4. insert sanitized string into database

OUTPUT

1. query field from database
2. `$output = Markdown($queryResult);`
3. display `$output`

Is that it?

Does PHP Markdown preclude the need for `htmlspecialchars` or `Pure HTML` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I evaluated the use of markdown in PHP some weeks ago (and decided not to use it, by the way). My thoughts:

- It might not be a good idea to run the markdown parser each time the output is rendered - parsing the comment is quite expensive and the usual blog comment (as an example) is far more often read than written. You should run the markdown parser BEFORE saving the user input into the database!
- Now the really tough problem: Markdown does not do any security checks by itself. All xss attacks are happily passed through. If you now think "no problem, I'll just strip_tags right after getting the user input", think again: it is quite possible that markdown creates the tags containing the XSS while processing the user input. So, you have to check the HTML code created by markdown for security problems - a very hard task which is very error prone. (That was the reason for not using it in my case - the benefit had no good ratio to the potential costs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 2 questions: (1) if I parse before saving to the database, how can users edit their articles? (2) what did you decide to do in lieu of Markdown?

Comment: Parser performance compromise - what if I saved 2 copies of user input, one copy of the original, one copy of the parsed. Then I'd only have to parse it once, and if the user wanted to edit I could give them the original and overwrite the parsed copy when they're done...

Comment: Storing 2 copies, one parsed and one original, was also my approach. Think its a good idea.

I looked into Markdown for a blog commenting module and used normal plain text with nl2br instead (adding a regular expression for highlighting links). For this use case, markdown was a little overkill, anyway.